# Get ID from Laravel eloquent query through a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

A `company` hasMany `users`, this relationship is achieved through a pivot table. I want to be able to get the `company.ID` of the company an individual user is related to:

```
$company_id = User::find(Auth()->$id)->companies->get('$id');
```

Unfortunately, I have also tried the `pluck()` method, but to no success. How can one retrieve a specific value from a formula like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in your user model you should add the relationship belongsTo (if the user belongs only to one company)

```
public function company(){

    return belongsTo('company');
}
```

then you can get the id of the company like this

```
$user      = User::find($id);
$company   = $user->company;
$companyId = $company->id;
```

I hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Well if the User can only be associated with one company, then your relationship should reflect this. Then you'd be able to use eager loading to do something like this:

```
// assumes the user is logged in
$user = Auth::user();

// assuming your relationship is set up correctly, you can do this:
echo $user->company->id;
```

You'd need to post the code relating to your models / relationships for a fuller answer, however.